# Weighted Uniform Strings

Tags: java, strings

### Problem

Adapted from [this HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weighted-uniform-string).

[image: Weighted Uniform String Problem]

Instead of printing `YES` or `NO`, I just want to return the `Set` of all possible weights for an input `String`.

I found this example to be illustrative

[image: Example Weighted Uniform Strings]

## Implementation

Some of my thoughts are in the implementation as comments

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class WeightedUniformStrings {
  public static Set<Long> getWeights(String s) {
    // I thought about using streams here, but I'm not using java 8
    Set<Long> weights = new HashSet<>();
    Map<Character, Long> consecutiveCharacterCounts = WeightedUniformStrings.getConsecutiveCharactersCounts(s);
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Long> entry : consecutiveCharacterCounts.entrySet()) {
      if (entry.getValue() != null && entry.getKey() != null) {
        long weight = WeightedUniformStrings.calculateWeight(entry.getKey());
        for (long i = 0; i < entry.getValue() + 1; i++) {
          weights.add(weight * i);
        }
      }
    }
    return weights;
  }

  private static long calculateWeight(char c) {
    // Could add a check to see if character is alphabetical
    return Character.toLowerCase(c) - 'a' + 1;
  }

  private static Map<Character, Long> getConsecutiveCharactersCounts(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
      return new HashMap<>();
    }

    Map<Character, Long> consecutiveCharacterCounts = new HashMap<>();
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    // I'm not a big fan of this initialization + for loop - but I haven't thought of a better alternative implementation
    char startingCharacter = chars[0];
    long consecutiveCharacterCount = 1;
    consecutiveCharacterCounts.put(startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);

    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
      char currentCharacter = chars[i];

      if (currentCharacter == startingCharacter) {
        consecutiveCharacterCount++;
      }

      if (currentCharacter != startingCharacter || i == chars.length - 1) {
        Long characterCount = consecutiveCharacterCounts.get(startingCharacter);
        if (characterCount == null || consecutiveCharacterCount > characterCount) {
          consecutiveCharacterCounts.put(startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
        }
      }

      // Doing this logical check twice feels weird
      if (currentCharacter != startingCharacter) {
        startingCharacter = currentCharacter;
        consecutiveCharacterCount = 1;
        Long characterCount = consecutiveCharacterCounts.get(startingCharacter);
        if (characterCount == null || consecutiveCharacterCount > characterCount) {
          consecutiveCharacterCounts.put(startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
        }
      }
    }

    return consecutiveCharacterCounts;
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed `for (long i = 0; i < entry.getValue() + 1; i++) ` should start at `1` not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid unnecessary math

> ```
>         for (long i = 0; i < entry.getValue() + 1; i++) {
> ```

As you noted in your comment, this should start at 1.

```
        for (long i = 1; i < entry.getValue() + 1; i++) {
```

But we can also simplify the end.

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= entry.getValue(); i++) {
```

We want to process `entry.getValue()` and then stop, so do that.  No need to determine the next place where we don't want to be.  The other way works, but this is easier to read.

We also don't need to use `long` here.  Because Java arrays can't be indexed past the range of an `int`, we can be sure that none of the counts will exceed the capacity of an `int`.  Of course, if we change to `int` here, we should change everywhere else as well.

#### Use a helper

> ```
>     consecutiveCharacterCounts.put(startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
>
>     for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
>       char currentCharacter = chars[i];
>
>       if (currentCharacter == startingCharacter) {
>         consecutiveCharacterCount++;
>       }
>
>       if (currentCharacter != startingCharacter || i == chars.length - 1) {
>         Long characterCount = consecutiveCharacterCounts.get(startingCharacter);
>         if (characterCount == null || consecutiveCharacterCount > characterCount) {
>           consecutiveCharacterCounts.put(startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
>         }
>       }
>
>       // Doing this logical check twice feels weird
>       if (currentCharacter != startingCharacter) {
>         startingCharacter = currentCharacter;
>         consecutiveCharacterCount = 1;
>         Long characterCount = consecutiveCharacterCounts.get(startingCharacter);
>         if (characterCount == null || consecutiveCharacterCount > characterCount) {
>           consecutiveCharacterCounts.put(startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

You can simplify this with a helper method:

```
public static void update(Map<Character, Long> counts, char c, int count) {
    Long oldCount = counts.get(c);
    if (oldCount == null || count > oldCount) {
        counts.put(c, count);
    }
}
```

Then we can change the bounds of the `for` loop.

```
    for (int i = 1, n = chars.length - 1; i < n; i++) {
      if (chars[i] == startingCharacter) {
        consecutiveCharacterCount++;
        continue;
      }

      update(consecutiveCharacterCounts, startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
      startingCharacter = chars[i];
      consecutiveCharacterCount = 1;
    }

    if (chars[chars.length - 1] == startingCharacter) {
      consecutiveCharacterCount++;
    } else {
      update(consecutiveCharacterCounts, startingCharacter, consecutiveCharacterCount);
      consecutiveCharacterCount = 1;
    }

    update(consecutiveCharacterCounts, chars[chars.length - 1], consecutiveCharacterCount);
```

Now we do one fewer iteration and on exiting the loop we do different processing.  This saves us having to do the extra check on every iteration of the loop.

Now we don't have to compare `currentCharacter` and `startingCharacter` three times.  Once is enough.

Using the `continue` saves us a level of indent over using an `else`.

We don't need to update the `Map` for the first one of each letter.  The logic works without that.

Comment: Your comments were fantastic! 

Out of curiosity is there a particular reason why you defined `n` in `for (int i = 1, n = chars.length - 1; i < n; i++)`? `n` doesn't seem to be used anywhere?

Not to get too pedantic, I was just curious.

Comment: Nice review! One thing as small advice: have a look at the new default functions in Map. For example, your helper function could simply be replaced by the following closed expression: `counts.put(c, Math.max(counts.getOrDefault(c, 0L), count))`  (matters of taste, I know... ;-))

Comment: @mtj oooohhh did not know about `getOrDefault` - that would simplify a decent amount of logic. Thanks!

Comment: The `n` is used in the `for` loop itself.  The `chars.length - 1` would probably be compiled out anyway, but this way I'm sure it will be.  I'm not sure that I'd go all the way to one lining with `getOrDefault`.  I'd just use it to get rid of `oldCount` and put it in the `if` directly.  A little more code to write but clearer and less compiled code.